# how to check that user is inactive for some specific duration?

Tags: codeigniter, logout

I want to log out the user if he is inactive for some specific duration. USing  sess_expiration in config file, it gives the timing from login not from inactive state.
So how can I do this using codeigniter?

Comment: If you wanted to do, say a 10 minute session. You could set sess_expiration to 10 minutes to start. Then, every time the user made a request to the server you could just reset it to 10 minutes. This is just a thought, I've never tried anything like this so I'm not sure if it'd work. Hence me not posting it as an answer.

Comment: @WillemEllis is saying is a good start problems youll run into is if you serve long articles or non-proggressive downloaded video that would take more then 10 minutes to view ... just my 2 cents

Comment: thax fr your response i vl try this...

Answer (score 0):

you can store the time in a session when the user logging in like this:

```
$_SESSION['loginTime'] = time();
```

and when the user do any action in the system, check if the user exceed the specified time

```
if($_SESSION['loginTime'] < time()+$yourtime){
    logout();
}else{
    $_SESSION['loginTime'] = time();
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't just setting the auth cookie expiration time to 10 min do the same thing?